# Arduino error while using ArduinoJson - call of overloaded 'println(....) is ambiguous'

Tags: python, json, arduino, esp8266, fastled

I was working with the FastLED library and I had to transfer data from a python program to Arduino. The only way I could find was to create JSON data and decode it on Arduino using ArduinoJSON.

But I ran into several errors while trying to use that data. Below is how to solve that issue

Comment: what errors? add the errors to the question

Answer (score 0):

So the error was due to the fact that arduino gets confused which overload of println() to choose. Now this can also occur when you are trying to run other functions such as add, subtract or use if condition on the data. Here is a more detailed explanation on ArduinoJSON website-

https://arduinojson.org/v6/error/call-of-overloaded-println-is-ambiguous/

To solve it do this-
store the value of that JSON data in a variable like this

```
int anger = doc["anger"]["vals"].as<int>();
```

I was working on something related to Emotions, thus anger. Anyways, for more details visit the above link

Comment: this is not an answer to the question